# Anylogic - getCellNumericValue

Tags: java, anylogic

I have written a few lines of code, the first line being

```
state=(int)Excelfile.getCellNumericValue(1,i,1);
```

where `i` is an index that increments and allows me to acquire data from every row of a particular column.

Now, I needed to stop acquiring data once the code reaches the last row of data. To do so, I tried to check whether `state` had a null value, so that I could end the function which acquires data but, the program produces an error before I can even check the value of state.

So, how can I end the function once it reaches the last plus one row of data  (the row after the last row of data)?

Note: The number of rows of data is not given, so I can't even iterate `i` until the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function `ExcelFile.getLastRowNum()` which returns the number of the last data row in a given sheet. Simply loop until your "i" reaches that number.

cheers

Comment: I apologize since I dint mention it before, but the column contains only 1's and 0's. So I guess I need to find a way to check for a null value ?

Comment: shouldn't make a difference. Just make sure to format the excel sheet correctly. Ideally, create a new sheet and paste your data. Then try the function on that new sheet. Else, select all rows *below* your data, right-click and select "delete". This will ensure AnyLogic interprets these rows as empty and returns the correct number of rows.